# Sort list according to values in nested dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested dict, I want get a sorted list (A-Z) of the base keys according to one of the nested values, `name`.

```
my_dict: {
    'RED':{'name':'Pen', 'number':5},
    'YEL':{'name':'Dog', 'number':1},
    'BLU':{'name':'Ball', 'number':3}
}
```

The correct output for the example would be:

```
my_list = ['BLU', 'YEL', 'RED']
```

At the moment, I have an ugly solution, it relies on the code always being 3 chars long.

```
my_list = []
for code in my_dict:
    my_list.append(my_dict[code]['name'] + code)
my_list = sorted(my_list)
my_list = [x[-3:] for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) argument of the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
my_dict = {
    'RED':{'name':'Pen', 'number':5},
    'YEL':{'name':'Dog', 'number':1},
    'BLU':{'name':'Ball', 'number':3}
}

my_list = sorted(my_dict, key = lambda x: my_dict[x]['name'])

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['BLU', 'YEL', 'RED']
```

Comment: Wow that's it. I looked into the 'key' argument but had trouble, and couldn't find many other nested examples. It seems simple now!
Thank you.